# Possible to boot Linux on MacBook Pro in screen mirroring mode vs dual screen?

Tags: macbook-pro

Looking for a “bios” toggle to tell HDMI output to mirror display vs split screen (at hardware-level vs OS-level). Not sure this exists…

Answer (score 0):

It does not.

The BIOS screens that you see on modern PCs, besides not being BIOS (rather UEFI) are just not available to modern Macs. That's what you get when you build the software *AND* the hardware. You don't need a *separate interface* to adjust the hardware, it is all done from inside macOS.

That said, it is possible to make *some* changes that take effect pre-boot, using the nvram command

`nvram -p`

Should give you all the settings currently set in non-volitale RAM. Many of which you can set yourself. A quick search should turn up resources that show the possibilities.

Though I doubt you can do what you want to do there. Those settings are controlled exclusively by macOS, so you would likely have to set them inside the OS of anything you booted the Mac from.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Steve. Would you happen to know how to disable internal display while keeping keyboard and trackpad functional?

Comment: Sorry no. If you have a laptop you can still work on it while closed but for iMacs, no idea.